# From Discount Factor to Zero rate

Tags: zero-coupon, discount-factor-curve

[image]

Hello guys, starting from this picture, which is the method that you usually use in order to find Zero Rate from Discount Factor?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried F1 F1?

Comment: Also, the discount factor is right next to it and all pricing engines use it automatically. The help desk most likely will not show you the calculation but there is a lengthy white paper for icvs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discount factor, zero rates, zero curve from BBG](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49527/discount-factor-zero-rates-zero-curve-from-bbg). It seem this is where you got the screenshot from.